# Mongodb doesn't return the correct document num in a high load

Tags: mongodb

I am new to stack overflow. If there isn't any wrong with the question sorry.

I have a nodejs web server application and it will be writing data to a mongodb database that is running in locally as a replica set. I want to write to a collection and when a document number limit reached I want to stop it.

So what I did was I first look for the number of the documents in a collection and if that num is lower than the max document num nodejs will write it to the db. But when it reached the max num nodejs will ignore writing data to mongodb.

This is the function

```
async add_Server_Info_To_Db() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            if (await client.db("db").collection("col").countDocuments() === 10) {
                reject("max reached");
            } else {
                const genid = await random_Things_Gen.id_Gen();
                await client.db("db").collection("col").insertOne({ _id: genid });
                resolve();
            };
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        };
    });
};
```

This function get called every time a new request hit the server. This function works when a small load hit the nodejs server. But when nodejs is receiving a high number of request this function not works. It will overflow the max document num.

So for that what I did was when I add data to mongodb I will first look if it is written to the collection and then nodejs will resolve the promise

This is the function

```
async add_Server_Info_To_Db() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            if (await client.db("db").collection("col").countDocuments() === 10) {
                reject("max reached");
            } else {
                const genid = await random_Things_Gen.id_Gen();
                await client.db("db").collection("col").insertOne({ _id: genid });
                while (true) {
                    await client.db("db").collection("col").findOne({ _id: genid }).then(() => {
                        resolve();
                    });
                };
            };
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        };
    });
};
```

This works for me.

My problem is why does it happen. mongodb wants to return the correct num

Comment: I think I'm a little bit confused about the original code here. The `if()` statment triggers an operation against the database to count the number of documents present. Based on the results of that operation the app then _separately_ inserts a new document. These are two different points in time, so it seems likely that concurrent requests will change the number of documents in the collection between those two operations.  Separately - what's your goal with doing this? Maybe there is a different approach altogether to achieve this.

Comment: my goal is to stop adding more documents to a collection in mongodb when a limit reached. I know capped collections can limit the documents in mongodb. But when a max limit reached in capped collection mongodb will remove the ones that is added and add new document to it. I don't want to mongodb to do that. I want mongodb to stop adding documents to collection when a limit reached. Is there a way to do that

Comment: This isn't really doable directly. You might be able to use transactions to achieve this, but that doesn't feel like it should be necessary or a scalable approach long term. You could also think about using a unique index and only allowing the client to submit docs with values `1` through `10` or something. You could also just reuse existing documents, marking them `available` or something like that. But it's still not clear what application functionality you are trying to provide by having this 10 document limit.